# How to display the state in another page

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm making a model for a real estate website, there's a select on the home page between 'rent' or 'purchase' and it's working fine, I'm storing the results in a state (the searchResults in the image) and I can display it on the page itself (where I circled in blue). but my objective is to display the results not on the home page, but on this other page /imoveis, so I'm trying to receive the state as props on it, but it's not working. Would this be a correct way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do that:

1. either pass the state as props to other component, and manage the state from there.
2. if you think that you are going to use the state in many components, then passing the state as property to many components can be daunting, you could use `useContext`, and `createContext()` to provide a global state to all components

unfortunately, I can't produce a code for you, you need to provide some code.